# Insert new rows in dataframe with conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, rows

This is my data:

```
df <- data.table(loc.id = c(22,22,23,23,23,24,24,24,25,25,25,27,27,27,27),
                 month = sample(c(1:12), 15, replace = TRUE))

    loc.id month
 1:     22     1
 2:     22     4
 3:     23    12
 4:     23    10
 5:     23     7
 6:     24     4
 7:     24     3
 8:     24    11
 9:     25     2
10:     25     3
11:     25     4
12:     27     1
13:     27     5
14:     27    12
15:     27     1
```

For each `loc.id`, I have some months. What I want to do is insert new rows in the `df`. For each `loc.id`, I want to insert two additional rows: one row with month value equal to `min(month) - 1` in `df` and another row with month value equal to `max(month) + 1`

My final data should look like this:

```
    loc.id month
 1:     22     1
 2:     22     4
 3:     22     0 # min(month) - 1
 4:     22     5 # max(month) + 1

 5:     23    12
 6:     23    10
 7:     23     7
 8:     23     6 # min(month) - 1
 9:     23     13 # max(month) + 1

10:     24     4
11:     24     3
12:     24    11
13:     24     2 # min(month) - 1
14:     24    12 # max(month) + 1
 .
 .
```

I have managed to add these as columns but I need to add them as rows

```
  df %>%
    group_by(loc.id) %>%
    mutate(month.min = min(month) - 1,
           month.max = max(month) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
dfmm <- df[, .(min.month = min(month) - 1, max.month = max(month) + 1), by = loc.id
           ][, melt(.SD, id = 1)][, .(loc.id, month = value)]

rbindlist(list(df, dfmm))
```

or a shorter option as suggested by @Frank in the comments:

```
df[, rbind(.SD, .(range(month) + c(-1,1))), by = loc.id]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     loc.id month
>  1:     22     5
>  2:     22     6
>  3:     23     1
>  4:     23     3
>  5:     23     6
>  6:     24     4
>  7:     24     8
>  8:     24     2
>  9:     25    12
> 10:     25     7
> 11:     25     5
> 12:     27     8
> 13:     27    12
> 14:     27     9
> 15:     27    10
> 16:     22     4
> 17:     23     0
> 18:     24     1
> 19:     25     4
> 20:     27     7
> 21:     22     7
> 22:     23     7
> 23:     24     9
> 24:     25    13
> 25:     27    13
> ```

If you want to order them, you could do:

```
rbindlist(list(df, dfmm))[order(loc.id)]
```

---

Or using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(loc.id) %>% 
  summarise(min.month = min(month) - 1,
            max.month = max(month) + 1) %>% 
  gather(key, val, -1) %>% 
  select(loc.id, month = val) %>% 
  bind_rows(df, .)
```

or (inspired by the `data.table`-approach of @Frank):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(loc.id) %>% 
  do(data.frame(month = range(.$month) + c(-1,1))) %>% 
  bind_rows(df, .)
```

---

Used data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(2018)
df <- data.table(loc.id = c(22,22,23,23,23,24,24,24,25,25,25,27,27,27,27),
                 month = sample(c(1:12), 15, replace = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `do(...)` and `add_row(...)`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(loc.id) %>% 
  do(add_row(., loc.id = rep(unique(.$loc.id), 2),
                month = c(min(.$month) - 1, max(.$month) + 1))) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 25 x 2
   # loc.id month
    # <dbl> <dbl>
 # 1    22.    7.
 # 2    22.    2.
 # 3    22.    1.
 # 4    22.    8.
 # 5    23.    5.
 # 6    23.    7.
 # 7    23.    7.
 # 8    23.    4.
 # 9    23.    8.
# 10    24.    9.
# ... with 15 more rows
```